# R, tbl_summary, treating continuous variables correctly

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am having a similar problem to [what this user reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037898/tbl-summary-and-numeric-variables).  Variables that are numeric and continuous are being treated as categorical.  Lets just use the cars dataset as well so that we have something reproducible to work with.  Lets say I simply do:

```
tbl_summary(mtcars)
```

[image]

Most of the variables will be treated as continuous but cyl, gear and carb for instance will be treated as categorical.  I understand (per that other question) how to treat ALL of the variables as continuous, but what if I like most of my table and just want to change gear to be treated as continuous for instance?  Is that possible?

In my real dataset, the variable I would like to be treated as continuous is already a numeric variable and I don't really see why its being treated as categorical, so I want to specify that gtsummary should treat that specific one as continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `?tbl_summary`, the `type` argument takes a named `list`.  So, if we need the `gear` as 'continuous', specify that alone as a `list` in the `type` and it will be taken as that type while the other variables will be automatically judged

```
library(gtsummary)
tbl_summary(mtcars, type = list(gear ~ "continuous"))
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. Explicitly specifying the data type with the `type=` argument solves the issue for a standalone summary table.

It causes problems if you want to dynamically supply a list of row variables. It raises error when the listed variable (`type = list(gear ~ "continuous2")`)  is not in the provided list of row variables.

It would be better to be able to globally suppress this functionality.

Comment: you can submit a feature request to add this option on the gtsummary GitHub page

Comment: You can also use `type = list(where(is.numeric) ~ "continuous2")` to assign all numeric columns at once.